How to calculate Variance (dispersion)?
I had an contest in Mathematics and I had a very unusual task from probability theory.
The task is the following:
"There are 8 black pencils and 12 pencils pens in the box. I randomly pick out 2 pencils without putting back.  How to calculate the variance of the two black pencils in my selection?".
My solution:
(P0) Probability of taking 0 black pen = 12/20 x 11/19 ;
(P1) Probability of taking 1 black pen= 8/20 x 12/19 + 12/20 x 8/19 ;
(P2) Probability of taking 2 black pens = 8/20 x 7/19 ;
E(x) = 0 * P0 + 1 * P1 + 2 * P2 = 0,8 ;
D(X) = 0^2P0 + 1^2P1 + 2^2*P2 - 0,8^2 ;
Is this an appropriate solution?

do you mean "the chance" instead of "the variance"?

This is not clear.  An event doesn't have a variance.  If you drew two pencils (unrestricted) you could ask for the variance of the number black ones in your selection, for example.

unfortunately, no. I was definitely asked to calculate the "variance". calculating the "chance" would be too easy :)

lulu, yes! that seems to be it. How to calculate the variance of the two black pencils in my selection?

What I am saying:  let $X$ be the number of black pencils in your selection.  Thus, $X\in {0,1,2}$.  It makes sense to compute the variance of $X$, which you can work out by hand.

@user25101315 What do you mean by "variance"? As mentioned above, the term "variance" applies to a random variable, not to an event.

Probability of taking 0 black pen= 12/2011/19 = P0 ;
Probability of taking 1 black pen= 8/2012/19 + 12/208/19 = P1 ;
Probability of taking 2 black pens = 8/207/19 = P2 ;
E(x) = 0 * P0 + 1 * P1 + 2 * P2 = 0,8 ;
D(X) = 0^2P0 + 1^2P1 + 2^2*P2  - 0,8^2 ;
Is it correct solution?

Yes, that is the variance of the random variable I mentioned.
